# Two same mysql queries with different execution plans

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am struggling with a mysql problem.

I have two exact same queries, just the item_id at the end is different, but they return different execution plans when I execute them with analyze/explain.

This results in a huge difference of time needed to return a result.

The query is something like

```
explain select `orders`.*, 
 (select count(*) from `items` 
  inner join `orders_items` on `items`.`id` = `orders_items`.`item_id` 
  where `orders`.`id` = `orders_items`.`order_id` 
   and `items`.`deleted_at` is null) as `items_count`, 
 (select count(*) from `returns` 
  where `orders`.`id` = `returns`.`order_id` 
   and `returns`.`deleted_at` is null) as `returns_count`, 
 (select count(*) from `shippings` 
  where `orders`.`id` = `shippings`.`order_id` 
   and `shippings`.`deleted_at` is null) as `shippings_count`, 
 (select count(*) from `orders` as `laravel_reserved_2` 
  where `orders`.`id` = `laravel_reserved_2`.`recurred_from_id` 
   and `laravel_reserved_2`.`deleted_at` is null) as `recurred_orders_count`, 
 (select COALESCE(SUM(orders_items.amount), 0) from `items` 
  inner join `orders_items` on `items`.`id` = `orders_items`.`item_id` 
  where `orders`.`id` = `orders_items`.`order_id` 
  and `items`.`deleted_at` is null) as `items_sum_orders_itemsamount`, 
 `orders`.*, 
 `orders_items`.`item_id` as `pivot_item_id`, 
 `orders_items`.`order_id` as `pivot_order_id`,
 `orders_items`.`amount` as `pivot_amount`, 
 `orders_items`.`id` as `pivot_id` 
from `orders` 
inner join `orders_items` on `orders`.`id` = `orders_items`.`order_id` 
where `orders_items`.`item_id` = 497 
 and `import_finished` = 1 
 and `orders`.`deleted_at` is null 
order by `id` desc limit 50 offset 0;
```

As you can see it is a laravel/eloquent query.

This is the execution plan for the query above:

[image]

But when I change the item_id at the end it return the following execution plan

[image]

It is absolutely random. 30% of the item_id's return the faster one and 70% return the slower one and I have no idea why. The related data is almost the same for every item we have in our database.

I also flushed the query cache to see if this was causing the different exec plans but no success.
I am googlin' since 4 hours but I can't find anything about this exact problem.

Can someone of you guys tell me why this hapens?

Thanks in advance!!

Edit 01/21/2023 - 19:04:

Seems like mysql don't like to order by columns which are not defined in the related where clause, in this case the pivot table orders_items.

I just replaced the

```
order by id
```

with

```
order by orders_items.order_id
```

This results in a 10 times faster query.

Comment: Is that 10x reproducible?  (Or was it due to caching.)  Changing id to order_id changes the query!!

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables; we may have further performance suggestions.

Comment: "order by `id`" -- Which table is that in?

Comment: What table is `import_finished` in?

Answer (score 1):

A query using different execution plans just because of a different parameter can have several reasons. The simplest explanation would be the position of the used item_id in the relevant index. The position in the index may affect the cost of using the index which in turn may affect if it is used at all. (this is just an example)

It is important to note that the explain statement will give you the planned execution plan but maybe not the actually used one.

[EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze) is the command which will output the actually used execution plan for you. It may still yield different results for different parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed the "id" to "orders_items.order_id" since mysql seem to have a problem with ordering by columns which are not included in the where clause. now the query runs almost 10 times faster...

Comment: @DominicOlearczyk Could you post the modified query that is 10x faster?  Edit and Insert with date/time please.  Thank you.

Comment: I've seen as many as 6 different explain plans for one query.  Diff constants (as with your 497), more rows one time versus the other, maybe even the phase of the moon.

Answer (score 0):

```
ON `orders`.`id` = `orders_items`.`order_id`

    where  `orders_items`.`item_id` = 497
      and  ???.`import_finished` = 1
      and  `orders`.`deleted_at` is null
    order by  ???.`id` desc
    limit  50 offset 0;
```

One order maps to many order items, correct?

So, `ORDER BY orders.id` is different than `ORDER BY orders_items.item_id`.

Does `item_id` = 497 show up in many different `orders`?

So, think about which `ORDER BY` you really want.

Meanwhile, these *may* help with performance:

```
orders_items:  INDEX(order_id, item_id)
returns:  INDEX(order_id, deleted_at)
shippings:  INDEX(order_id, deleted_at)
laravel_reserved_2:  INDEX(recurred_from_id, deleted_at)
```